# Request not firing when returning to app from background

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm returning to my app which is in the background from a successful payment from another app. When returning, a patch request should be fired to change status from available to sold. The problem is that the request is never fired.

I use alamofire session manager to make the request. And the function making the request is used all over the project and it works. It is also not a server error or a threading error as it runs on the main thread and the server works through curl / swagger.

It seems to me that the app does not have internet connection or something of the sort when returning to the app. Loggs can be found down below. The request has been succesfully fired a couple of times, which makes be believe in the internet connection theory.

Here are some selected parts of the code.

```swift
lazy var manager: SessionManager = {
        let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
        sessionManager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 40
        sessionManager.adapter = OauthHandler.sharedInstance
        sessionManager.retrier = OauthHandler.sharedInstance
        return sessionManager
    }()

func authenticateRequestWithRouter(_ router: BaseRouter, shouldShowErrorAlert: Bool = true, _ completion: requestResponse?) {
        let request = router.asURLRequest()
        manager.request(request).validate().responseJSON() { [weak self] response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                completion?(true, data, nil)
            case .failure(let error):
                if shouldShowErrorAlert,
                    let errorMessage = self?.parseErrorMessage(fromData: response.data, request: request) {
                    self?.showErrorAlert(message: errorMessage)
                }
                completion?(false, response.data, error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Logs that have been occuring:

> Returning ENOTCONN because protocol has not yet been set up
>
> nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint [C7] Connection has no
>   local endpoint
>
> HTTP load failed (error code: -1005 [1:57])
>
> Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."
>
> Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 "Software caused connection abort"
>
> nw_protocol_boringssl_error(1584) [C1.1:2][0x102838b30] Lower protocol
>   stack error: 53

Comment: Where do you call this request method when app return from background?

Comment: @kubrickG When the app return from background it goes through appDelegate into another class. There the call is made.